# ReactJS getting CORS error while calling RapidAPI

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a CORS error from a dockerized ReactJS app. When I tested it locally it worked fine. But after I dockerized it and pushed it to Docker Desktop as port 3003, it gave an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://keto-diet.p.rapidapi.com/?protein_in_grams__lt=15&protein_in_grams__gt=5' from origin 'http://localhost:3003' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Here is my React code:

```
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://keto-diet.p.rapidapi.com/",
  params: {
    protein_in_grams__lt: '15',
    protein_in_grams__gt: '5'
  },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "myapikeyishere",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "keto-diet.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};
const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const ketoRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await axios.request(options);
    setProducts(response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ketoRecipes();
  }, []);
```

Here is the docker desktop
[image]

What should I do to avoid the CORS issues? Thanks

Comment: @AmithAG: Error messages are not code, and should not be formatted that way. The error message is a blockquote, and is readable when formatted as such. Please do not revert my edit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in the options

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
withCredentials: true,
credentials: "include"
```

This will allow the json format file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the API server-because it's a third-party API- you can try to use proxy.

I assume the server is expressjs

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/api',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://keto-diet.p.rapidapi.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
  })
);

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

to call this API, you can use minimalized url like

```js
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "/api/", // here
  params: {
    protein_in_grams__lt: '15',
    protein_in_grams__gt: '5'
  },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "myapikeyishere",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "keto-diet.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};
```